# how to insert data in database from netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have used this query to create a table:

```
create table accounts
(
    AccountID int primary key auto_increment,
    UserName varchar(30),
    Aadhar varchar(12),
    Balance float
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

And used this query in netbeans for inserting data:

```
INSERT INTO bankdb.accounts(UserName, Aadhar,Balance) VALUES(?,?,?);
```

My problem is UserName is not getting inserted in table even though I used:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);    
ps.setString(1, Name);
ps.setString(2, Aadhar); 
ps.setFloat(3, balance);

ps.executeLargeUpdate();
rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
```

There is also no error in netbeans.Only UserName is not getting inserted in database rest of data is getting inserted.

Comment: Did you debug this? I don't see any apparent problem with the code, assuming it is executed as shown.

Comment: i didn't debug this but everything gets inserted instead of username

Comment: I assume you checked that the variable `Name` actually has a name in it ?

Comment: yes variable Name gets its String from a textfield

Comment: Did you check that? A quick bit of debug?

Comment: So Aadhar and balance are getting inserted but the `username` column in the database is empty?

Comment: yes debug doesn't help the problem

Comment: yes Aadhar and Balance are getting inserted

Comment: Then it's not an issue with mysql. The variable `Name` is empty.

Comment: but text gets written in textfield

Comment: i have used Name=namefield.getText();

Comment: Debug this and make sure that `Name` has a value that is not empty.

Comment: i have debugged it and Name is storing null

Comment: Null means empty

Answer (score 0):

You should try with a hardcoded string, like:

```
ps.setString(1, "Test Name");
```

If that's work, check if your variable is correct.

Also, make sure it's not some encoding problem.

Comment: Your suggestions are perfectly valid as comments, but do not rise to the level of being an answer.

Comment: True, but this is the most accurate I can give based on the current question. I need more details from the asker.